# Encabezado de tabla fijo con scroll horizontal

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tengo una tabla en la cual necesito poner un encabezado fijo cuando se mueve hacia abajo, debido a que hay muchos datos a mostrar. El problema está en que tengo muchas columnas que mostrar, y estas columnas abarcan más del ancho de la pantalla.

Ya busqué bastantes maneras de realizar lo que busco, lo intento realizar con `Jquery`, pero si se baja poco el encabezado se vuelve loco, y cuando se baja más se mantiene el encabezado, pero las columnas del encabezado ya no concuerdan con las columnas del contenido, y no logré hacer que el encabezado se mueva conforme al scroll horizontal.

En este enlace tengo un ejemplo de lo que "logré" hacer por ahora:

```js
var stickyOffset = $('.sticky').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var sticky = $('.sticky'), 
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= stickyOffset) sticky.addClass('fixed');
  else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
});
```

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 40;
}

body {
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

table {
  border-width: 1;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 200px 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  padding: 5px;
  /*NOTE: th padding must be set explicitly in order to support IE*/
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #b1b1b1;
}

tbody td {
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

td {
  text-align: right;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Contenido</p>
    <p>Contenido</p>
    <p>Contenido</p>
    <p>Contenido</p>
    <p>Contenido</p>
    <p>Contenido</p>
  </body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr class="sticky">
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Cliente</th>
      <th>Descripcion</th>
      <th>Notas</th>
      <th>Fecha de llegada</th>
      <th>Fecha ejecucion</th>
      <th>Usuario</th>
      <th>Informacion</th>
      <th>Informacion</th>
      <th>Informacion</th>
      <th>Informacion</th>
      <th>Informacion</th>
      <th>Informacion</th>
      <th>Informacion</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
      <td>Datos</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas jQuery o JavaScript para esto. Se puede lograr sólo con HTML and CSS. La idea sería **hacer que las celdas de la cabecera tengan una posición sticky**... ¡sólo eso! Con 4 líneas de CSS lo tendrías ya hecho:

```
th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```css
/* solución: hacer las celdas de cabecera tener position:sticky */
tr:first-child th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

table {
  border-width: 1;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 200px 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
}

th {
  padding: 5px;
  /*NOTE: th padding must be set explicitly in order to support IE*/
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #b1b1b1;
}

tbody td {
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

td {
  text-align: right;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<p>Contenido</p>
<p>Contenido</p>
<p>Contenido</p>
<p>Contenido</p>
<p>Contenido</p>
<p>Contenido</p>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Descripcion</th>
    <th>Notas</th>
    <th>Fecha de llegada</th>
    <th>Fecha ejecucion</th>
    <th>Usuario</th>
    <th>Informacion</th>
    <th>Informacion</th>
    <th>Informacion</th>
    <th>Informacion</th>
    <th>Informacion</th>
    <th>Informacion</th>
    <th>Informacion</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
    <td>Datos</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Contenido</p>
<p>Contenido</p>
<p>Contenido</p>
<p>Contenido</p>
<p>Contenido</p>
<p>Contenido</p>
```

Idealmente, cambiaría un poco la estructura del HTML (añadiendo `<thead>` y `<tbody>`), porque es mejor semánticamente y podría darse el caso de que tengas más de una fila de cabecera... pero eso ya sería otra historia.

Answer (score 0):

Hola compañero prueba a hacer como este ejemplo creo que es lo que buscas:

la cabecera que no quieres que se mueva:

```
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>My Header</h2>
</div>
```

este seria el css:

```
/* Style the header */
.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Page content */
.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the header with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the header gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

Y este seria el javascript para darle la funcionalidad:

```
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

// Get the header
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

// Add the sticky class to the header when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Espero que te sirva! saludos

Comment: Ya no se pone loco el encabezado al bajar la página. Pero todavía tengo un par de problemas, no sé si me di a explicar bien, es para un encabezado de tabla, y cuando el encabezado se fija a la pantalla todas las columnas se desacomodan y dejan de coincidir con el encabezado. A parte necesito que el encabezado quede fijo en la pantalla con respecto al movimiento vertical, sin embargo tengo que hacer que el scroll horizontal siga afectando al encabezado fijo de la tabla.

Comment: Haz un contenedor para el encabezado y otro para los datos, la posición de los contenedores es fija dentro de la tabla y pon overflow en el contenedor de los datos